# Is it acceptable that the verb "absorb" is used intransitively, especially in the medical and advertising communities?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammaticality

All references that I've come across list "absorb" only as a transitive verb, yet I find it used commonly in the medical and advertising community intransitively. For example, "Our vitamin C absorbs more quickly". I want to ask, what does it absorb, as absorb is a transitive verb needing an object: "Our brand of paper towel absorbs liquid  more quickly than brand X."--edited. On the other hand a word such as "assimilate" can be used both transitively and intransitively. Whether a word is transitive only or both transitive and intransitive seems to be rather arbitrary, and and I find people taking liberties to speed the process of making transitive verbs into intransitive verbs, for their convenience, I assume; so rather than say the vitamin C is absorbed into the bloodstream they will say the vitamin C absorbs into the bloodstream, which is grammatically incorrect. Adding "into the bloodstream" does not make it any less an intransitive usage in the latter case.

Comment: Consider: *the **farmer** tills the ground* / *the **ground** tills well*, or something along the lines of your question’s opening sentence: *a reference **editor** lists ‘absorb’ as transitive in a reference work* / *the **reference** lists ‘absorb’ as transitive* (or even ***’absorb** lists as transitive*).

Comment: Note that 'Our brand of paper towel absorbs more quickly than brand X.' is an intransitive usage whereas 'Our vitamin C absorbs more quickly' is a middle usage. I can't find either of these being licensed by a dictionary (it would have been helpful if you'd listed where you'd looked). I've tried ODO / CED / AHD / Collins / Macmillan / RHK Webster's / M-W / Longman. // The two usages you ask about may well be on their way to respectability. They're not confusing, and they're convenient, and English develops. // Your question is POB; probably some people are aware they're pushing the ...

Comment: boundaries of what is considered acceptable, while others just see their examples and bandwagon. Note that Quark and Svartvik famously wrote a paper proving that 'acceptability', even when pronounced upon by learned usage panels, is not a matter of black and white.

Comment: To Edwin Ashworth: I suppose my example of "Our brand paper of towels absorbs more quickly" appears to be an intransitve usage, but actually I believe the object is implied--it absorbs liquid more quickly. I really should have used, "Our brand of paper towels absorbs liquid more quickly."

Comment: By the way what is "POB"? I'm new to this site.

Comment: JEL -- I will gladly reframe my question; it does rather beg the question. But I was trying to think of a way to put my observation in question form.

Comment: JEL --I have changed the title; is it more acceptable now?

Comment: This happens a lot in English: the result is traditionally called a "middle voice" (because it parallels a construction of that name in Ancient Greek), and in more modern works an [unaccusative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb)

Comment: I've retracted my close vote because of your willingness to edit the question. I still find the question somewhat unfocused, but answerable (as suggested by @ColinFine in the comments, but more, almost too much more, comprehensively). "POB" means *answers* will be expressions of personal opinions, rather than justifiable and justified (with references, reasoning, etc.) expert opinions. "POB" is something of a stalking horse here.

Comment: I think you’re quite right and *Our vitamin C absorbs more quickly* is wrong but context could make the same construction grammatical.

*Our towel/sponge/cloth absorbs more quickly* works, does it not?

*Advertising* is built on not one but two vital planks… secondly anything technical but first and by far foremost, how senior is whoever thought up the idea?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - I agree that  _our towel/sponge/cloth absorbs more quickly_ works, but _our vitamin C absorbs more quickly_ is incorrect because it implies, grammatically speaking, that the vitamin C does the absorbing.

Comment: I suggest that whatever construct you choose to wrap it in, "vitamin C absorbs more quickly…" is and always wil be a misinterpretation of "vitamin C is absorbed more quickly…"

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - I agree; I was just pointing out why it's different than _the paper towel absorbs more quickly_. For probably a couple decades now I've been trying to get a particular foundation, that does anti-aging research and manufactures and sells supplements, to correct their ad copy regarding this erroneous construction, to no avail.

Comment: Dustin G, what on Earth?

For prolly a couple of decades you've been trying to get a particular foundation, that does anti-aging research and manufactures and sells supplements, to correct their ad copy regarding this erroneous construction, to no avail.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin - I didn't check back in to see your response to my last comment on the same day, until now. My feeling is that if they are so inaccurate and cavalier in this type of thing, how am I to trust the more important aspects of their articles? To be fair, it is usually the ad copy that has this particular grammatical error lately, not the actual articles, although I've seen it there too in the past.

Comment: @Dustin G - I'd forgotten this thread existed… and still, you're wholly right. On most days, I have exactly your reaction to one advertisement or another.

I wish there was a special section the deep inside Advertising Standards Agency for that kind of thing and since there isn't, I guess the only options are to vent our spleen here or to call on the huge, far-reaching power of somewhere such as the Campaign for Real English…